# Komma nach und vor Strich

Tags: punctuation

Welche Variante ist korrekt?

1. Das Schnabeltier, das ich gesehen habe, als ich in den Wald gegangen war, – ich glaube aber, das könnte ein Biber gewesen sein, – hat nicht versucht, mich anzugreifen, und ist nur weggekrochen, als es mich gesehen hat.
2. Das Schnabeltier, das ich gesehen habe, als ich in den Wald gegangen war –, ich glaube aber, das könnte ein Biber gewesen sein –, hat nicht versucht, mich anzugreifen, und ist nur weggekrochen, als es mich gesehen hat.

Comment: Wie es aussieht, hast du bereits zwei weitere Varianten ausgeschlossen: "3. nur Komma" bzw. "4. nur Gedankenstrich". Vielleicht kannst Du noch kurz erklären, warum diese beiden Versionen für dich nicht in Frage kommen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beides falsch. Dieser Gedankeneinschub erklärt den vorderen Halbsatz und wird deshalb auch nicht mit einem Komma von diesem abgetrennt. Das Komma, das ihn vom Hauptsatz *hat nicht versucht* abtrennt, muss außerhalb der Gedankenstriche stehen.

> **Das Schnabeltier, das ich gesehen habe, als ich in den Wald gegangen war – ich glaube aber, das könnte ein Biber gewesen sein –** , hat nicht versucht, mich anzugreifen, und ist nur weggekrochen, als es mich gesehen hat.

Aber ganz generell werden Gedankenstriche im Deutschen nur sehr sparsam verwendet, und auch nicht für Einschübe ganzer Sätze. Entweder für Einschübe von Gruppen

> Das Schnabeltier – Ornidingsbums anawumms –, das ich gesehen habe, als ich in den Wald gegangen war, hat nicht versucht, mich anzugreifen, und ist nur weggekrochen, als es mich gesehen hat.

oder für Anfügungen ganzer Sätze, die in keinem direkten Zusammenhang stehen:

> Das Schnabeltier, das ich gesehen habe, als ich in den Wald gegangen war, hat nicht versucht, mich anzugreifen, und ist nur weggekrochen, als es mich gesehen hat – oder war es ein Biber?